# Except the return value, does a variable's address must be sent to a function to modify its value in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I try to understand when a variable's value gets modified by passing through a function in C.

I know that in C, there's two ways to change variable's value :

- Using the return value of a function
- Passing a variable's address to modify its content

Here's the code :

```
// by address

void foo(int *nb)
{
    *nb = 10;
}

int main(void)
{
     int nb = 5;
     foo(&nb);
     printf("%i\n", *nb); // It prints 10
}

// Code to explain

void foo(char **tab)
{
    tab[2] = "44";
}

void bar(char *str)
{
    str[1] = 'a';
}

int main(void)
{
    char **tmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4);
    char *str = strdup("Hello");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        tmp[i] = malloc(3);

    tmp[0] = "11";
    tmp[1] = "22";
    tmp[2] = "33";
    tmp[3] = NULL;

    foo(tmp);        // It modifies tmp's value
    bar(str);        // It modifies str's value

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", tmp[i]);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Output:
11
22
44
Hallo

Expected:
11
22
33
Hello

I was expecting to send a copy to the function but at the end, both string and char ** are modified.
Why variables are modified here ?

Comment: You're sending a copy of the address. As you said, you can modify the value by "Passing a variable's address to modify its content", and that's exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: Why variables tmp and str takes the modification ? If I want to pass them as address, I must send &tmp and &str, no ?

Comment: No, because they're pointers. So when you're passing `str` you're passing around an address, not a value. And then you dereference those addresses in your functions (by using them as arrays but actually performing pointer arithmetics) modifying the values at those addresses.

Comment: `tmp` holds the address of the memory you allocated with `malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4)` and `str` holds the address of the memory you allocated with `strdup("Hello")`. By dereferencing those with `[]` you access the memory at those addresses.

Comment: `foo(tmp)` cannot modify `tmp`, since `tmp` is passed by value.  If `tmp` is the address of something, `foo(tmp)` can modify the pointed-at something.   If `tmp` points at the (first element of) an array, `foo(tmp)` can modify the elements of that array.   Similarly, `bar(str)` cannot change the value of `str`, but CAN modify whatever `str` points at.

Comment: There is an unrelated problem (memory leak) in your code. `tmp` is an array of pointers. You allocate memory in a loop with `tmp[i] = malloc(3);`. When you assign `tmp[0] = "11";` you don't copy the string `"11"` into this memory. Instead you replace the pointer to the allocated memory with a pointer to the srting literal `"11"`. So either omit the `malloc` before assigning the pointer or use `memcpy(tmp[0], "11", 3)`. The same applies to the assignment in `foo()`. It doesn't modify the string contents but makes the pointer point to a different string, i.e. to the string literal `"44"`.

Comment: I get your point Bodo, I was modifying tmp's address when assigning tmp with string litteral.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment on `foo(tmp)` says “It modifies tmp's value,” but this is not correct. `tmp` is a pointer, and the value of the pointer is not modified by `foo`. The call `foo(tmp)` passes the value of `tmp` to `foo`, and then `foo` modifies the things that are pointed to. It changes `tmp[2]` to point to `"44"`. `tmp[2]` is one of the things pointed to by `tmp`; it is not `tmp`.

Similarly, in `bar(str)`, `str` is a pointer, and the value of the pointer is not changed by `var`. Rather, `bar` changes one of the characters in the string that `str` points to.